# Array with 1 element is evaluated as that element when in brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const items = ['one'];
const obj = {
  'one': 'foobar'
};
console.log(obj[items]);
```

The console output is "foobar".

Why/how does `[items]` evaluate to "one"? Will this throw an error in strict mode?

Comment: I know I've seen questions like this before, but can't find one to mark as a duplicate.

Comment: I figured it would have been asked before, but since I couldn't find one either I decided to ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a key of type Array. So your array is converted to string first and code is equivalent to

```
const items = ['one'];
const obj = {
  'one': 'foobar'
};
console.log(obj[items.toString()]);
```

Interestingly it would not work if you will try to add `Symbol` to your items array.

Also, because of the way Array.toString works, you can have `items` with multiple elements, and still get the same behaviour:

```
const items = [1,2];

const obj = {
   '1,2': 'foobar'
}

console.log(obj[items]); // also works
```

Comment: @besseddrest glad it help! Don't forget to accept answer. And accept answer to questions you ask on SO in general.